# Is there a way to dynamically assert the Responses with CompareToSet in SpecFlow

Tags: c#, testing, .net-core, bdd, specflow

I have two Data Service EnquiryType and EnquirySource the Common Step between them is when I try to assert the response for both in there feature files, currently I am distinguishing the Scenario Step with the Data Service name, but I want to separate out the assertion step and use that for both Data Service.

Current Logic

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The step that gets all of the enquiry types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [Given(@"I request all enquiry types")]
    public async Task RequestAllEnquiryTypes()
    {
        try
        {
            var results = await EnquiryTypesApi.GetEnquiryTypes(enquiryTypeData);
            enquiryTypes = new List<EnquiryTypeModel>(results.Results);
            FeatureSteps.statusCode = results.StatusCode;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Makes sure that the retrieved enquiries types match the expected  data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data">The expected enquiry type data.</param>
    [Then("The following Enquiry Type result is returned:")]
    public void ThenTheFollowingResultIsReturned(TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table data)
    {
        data.CompareToSet<EnquiryTypeModel>(enquiryTypes);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The step that gets all of the enquiry sources.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [Given(@"I request all enquiry sources")]
    public async Task RequestAllEnquirySources()
    {
        try
        {
            var results = await EnquirySourcesApi.GetEnquirySources(enquirySourceData);
            enquirySources = new List<EnquirySourceModel>(results.Results);
            FeatureSteps.statusCode = results.StatusCode;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Makes sure that the retrieved enquiries sources match the expected  data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data">The expected enquiry source data.</param>
    [Then("The following Enquiry Source result is returned:")]
    public void ThenTheFollowingResultIsReturned(TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table data)
    {     
        data.CompareToSet<EnquirySourceModel>(enquirySources);
    }
```

What I want to achieve

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Makes sure that the Result match the expected  data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data">The expected data.</param>
    [Then("The following result is returned:")]
    public void ThenTheFollowingResultIsReturned(TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table data)
    {     
        data.CompareToSet(dynamicObject);
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify what "DS" means? This is not an industry standard term.

Comment: Sorry DS means Data Service

Comment: Ok. Is there a problem with two separate step definitions? If each `Then` step is a single line of code, I don't see a benefit to creating an abstraction. Especially since there is no easy way of doing this in SpecFlow.

Comment: But in future there might be a lot of data services, and will have to repeat this same step definition everytime distinguishing each with Data Service name. Because of this I thought of separating it out, but if it's complicated to do so then it might not be worth wasting my time.

Comment: Even if you need to add 50 data services, each step is a one-liner. It isn't much code to maintain, and each step is loosely coupled. They shouldn't need to change very often. I really think you are over complicating this.